# drupal mod_rewrite, add an exception for path/module

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, drupal, shibboleth

I have a Drupal installation configured with [shib_auth](https://www.drupal.org/project/shib_auth) and some mod_rewrite rules in the top level directory to ensure that users hiting the site are signed in.
This is working correctly.

But I have one module that provides a sort of API which is secured by Oauth.
I need an exception so the API path does not get-redirected to SSO.

The path I want to except is: https://base-url/h5p/d2l/launch

I have attempted to use:
    RewriteRule ^h5p - [L]
But this doesn't appear to be working.

The full mod_rewrite rule is below:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#RewriteRule ^h5p - [L]
RewriteRule ^Shibboleth\.sso - [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  So everyone is clear you're trying to get all users redirected to SSO, but you want the API to be able to authenticate against Drupal at a custom path?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response.
No the API does not need to be able to authenticate against Drupal. It is an un authenticated public API.
I merely need to exempt the API path from the re-write rule. As the API expects a POST request which is stripped out after the SSO process is complete.
The SSO or any Drupal auth is not required on the api path.

I hope this is clearer

Comment: Is `/h5p/d2l/launch` an actual path? Or is it a pretty URL that Drupal is supposed to handle?

Comment: Its a pretty path that drupal handles.
actual path would be /sites/all/modules/h5p/views